# Other 2D extensions of the reals

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field

The complex numbers are one instance of an extension of the reals. But are there others? For example, with complex numbers, $i^2=-1$, but there are other ways of defining $i$ which also result in an abelian group. Five other instances are

1. $i^2=-1-i$
2. $i^2=1$
3. $i^2=-1+i$
4. $i^2=1-i$
5. $i^2=1+i$

There are also some extensions which are abelian, except for invertablity. Some of these are

1. $i^2=0$
2. $i^2=i$
3. $i^2=-i$

So, are these valid extensions of the reals? If they are, what makes $i^2=-1$ special compared to the rest of them?

Comment: Careful there. The equation $x^2=1+x$ has real roots $x=(1\pm\sqrt5)/2$, so if you declare $i^2=1+i$ you don't really go outside the reals. The structure $K=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\Bbb{R}\}$ is then simply isomorphic to a direct product of two copies of $\Bbb{R}$. Similarly, the first equation $x^2=-1-x$ has solutions in the usual complex numbers: $x=(-1\pm \sqrt{-3})/2$, and the structure you get is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$. The third possibility comes from $i^2=0$. The resulting system is known as the ring of dual numbers.

Comment: Anyway, the end result is that if $L$ is a 2-dimensional vector space equipped with an $\Bbb{R}$-linear multiplication such that in $L$ division by any non-zero element is possible, then $L$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$. The TL;DR; version: Either you get $\Bbb{C}$ or something were some rules of arithmetic break down.

Comment: And to answer the last question. There isn't anything very special about $i^2=-1$. Any quadratic equation with a negative discriminant gives you the complex numbers. More precisely. If you declare $a i^2+bi+c=0$ with $b^2-4ac<0$, then you can ALWAYS find real numbers $u,v$ such that $(u+iv)^2=-1$. So you might as well write things in terms of $(u+iv)$ instead of $i$, and be done with it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen IIRC, if $i\in\Bbb R$, $K$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ (and actually $K=\Bbb R$). It's isomorphic to a direct product $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ precisely when $i$ is complex. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I had in mind the ring $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-x-1)$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem that is isomorphic to the direct sum 
$$\Bbb{R}[x]/(x-\phi)\oplus\Bbb{R}[x]/(x-\overline{\phi})$$ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and $\overline{\phi}=(1-\sqrt5)/2$. That is the ring we end up with if we define a multiplication in the set of formal combinations $a+bi$ by declaring $i^2=1+i$. Sorry about not making that clear. Anyway, both those summands are isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the motivation for such - is there any advantage gain by it? What is it?